# Add URL anchor to wp_dropdown_pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the Wordpress function `wp_dropdown_pages()`, I'm trying to expand it by being able to add an argument to the parameters array that will append an anchor to the end of the URL produced. But I think there's an issue as the values that appear in the dropdown list are the page ID, and then WP redirects to an actual URL.

For example, the dropdown list when submitted will go to whatever page URL is selected in the dropdown, but I'd like to insert an argument of:

```
'anchor' => 'example'
```

and have the URL be returned as /parent/page/#example

Is there a hook or function I can do to pass through an anchor name to add to the end of the URL that gets redirected to?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I discovered this is actually alot easier than I thought. There's no need to go into the function at all, as I could just add the anchor to the end of the form action attribute.

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>#patient-stories" method="get">
```

This will now add the anchor to any URL that the dropdown list selects.